# PHP MYSQL INNER JOIN to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I had a two table,

First one : table **product** table product

```
| id | name   | code |
| 1  | blouse | AB1  |
| 2  | jeans  | BA2  |
| 3  | dress  | C61  |
```

and the second table **color** table color

```
| id_product | colors | amount |
|     1      | blue  |  50    |
|     1      | red   |  40    |
|     1      | yellow|  10    |
|     2      | white |  15    |
|     2      | blue  |  60    |
|     3      | purple|  110   |
```

**Query :** my query php

```
.../blabla
SELECT product.id, product.name, product.code,color.id_product, color.colors, color.amount
FROM product
INNER JOIN color 
ON product.id = color.id_product limit 1

while($query)) {
    $var[] = $query;
}
echo '{"status":'. json_encode($var).'}';
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{
    "status":{
        "1":{
            "id":"1",
            "code":"blouse",
            "id_product":"1",
            "colors":"blue",
            "amount":"50",
        }
    }
}
```

**what i want JSON like this :**

```
{
    "status":{ 
        "1":{  
            "id":"1",
            "code":"blouse",
            "id_product":"1",
            "colors":"blue",
            "amount":"50",
            "id_product":"1",
            "colors":"red",
            "amount":"40",
            "id_product":"1",
            "colors":"yellow",
            "amount":"10",
        }
    }
}
```

Need color into one array json, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should probably use group_concat to get them into a list and then use PHP to explode the list before encoding to json.

SQL Fiddle Here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba3b8/3

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, product.code,
color.id_product, color.colors, color.amount,
group_concat(color.colors) as clist,
group_concat(color.amount) as alist

from product, color
where product.id = color.id_product
group by color.id_product
```

Then in your PHP you would need to loop through the results, using explode to convert the list to an array and inserting the data into the results as needed PRIOR to using json_encode();

Answer (score 0):

You should use this query:

```
SELECT product.id, product.name, product.code
color.id_product, color.colors, color.amount
from product
INNER JOIN color 
ON product.id = color.id_product
where product.id=1
```

`LIMIT`will give you exactly one record.